Isabelle Jedit try to check file and show all errors
I am using Isabelle with JEdit on Windows, mostly because I'm interested in understanding exactly how powerful the sledgehammer tactic is.
I have the following extremely basic file and I'm trying to check it. This file is paraphrased from this question on Stack Overflow from the distant past.
I have a file add_assoc.thy.
section "stuff"

theory add_assoc
   imports Main
begin

function add :: "nat => nat => nat" where
"add 0 n = 0" |
"add (Suc m) n = Suc(add m n)"

end

I am pretty sure that the above file contains an error. The function definition for add is accepted by the system, but there's an error marker in JEdit next to end, but no additional information when I click on the stop-sign with an exclamation point in the middle.
I have a total of maybe ten minutes of experience clicking around in the JEdit interface, but I am stuck on one super basic thing.
How do I try to check this file or compile it?
Is there a way to check the file and just open up all of the errors in another buffer?

In Isabelle/JEdit, it's quite important where you place your cursor.
To read the error message, we have to put the cursor behind the marked error at end.
(Cursor position = red box.)

The error message Bad context for command end is not overly expressive, unfortunately.
What it tries to communicate is that some context has been opened that needs to be closed before we are allowed to close the theory context with end.
In this instance, the function definition command has opened a proof context, which we can inspect by moving the cursor one line up:

This particular output of proof goals is only there because I've ticked the Proof state checkbox.
Basically, Isabelle here expects a proof for the function to be well-defined.
So, let's fire up auto and sledgehammer and see what they come up with:

With this, we can easily complete the proof...

Note how the error marker is gone in this output.
Also the theory in the Theories-pane on the right stopped being red.
function, by the way, most definitely is not the function definition mechanism you want to use.
It not only requires the proof of non-overlapping cases, but we would need to go on to also prove termination if we wanted to actually work with add.
If you rephrase the definition with fun, Isabelle proves everything automatically.
So, the easiest fix to your theory would actually be to just drop the ction:
fun add :: "nat => nat => nat" where
  "add 0 n = 0" |
  "add (Suc m) n = Suc(add m n)"

